# Cannot display data in JavaFX TableView when using Properties

Tags: javafx, properties, tableview

I have read several threads on using Properties to display data in a JavaFX TableView and I can get all of these to work. Up until now I have been displaying data without problem in my TableView without Properties. However, moving forward I think I need to start using Properties, particularly as I want my TableView to be editable. I suspect that the problem is because all the examples I have seen use one object to display 1 row of data, whereas in my model I have one object (a `Field` object) per cell, though I can't think why this should be a problem.

Below is a VERY cut-down version of my `Field` class, enough for this test, but not enough to show its real use. I also have a test class `TableViewDemo`. Any help with this irksome problem would be much appreciated. Either it will be a silly mistake, or a fundamental problem with my design.

```
package javafxtest;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleObjectProperty;

public class Field {

    private final SimpleObjectProperty objectValue; //All the data is stored as an object, then cast to appropriate data type

    public Field(Object objValue) throws SQLException {
        if (objValue == null) {
            throw new SQLException("Field value is null");
        }
        this.objectValue = new SimpleObjectProperty(objValue);
    }

    public final String getStringValue() {
        return (String) this.objectValue.get();
    }

    public final int getIntValue() {
        return (Integer) this.objectValue.get();
    }

    public final double getDoubleValue() {
        return (Double) this.objectValue.get();
    }

    public final boolean getBooleanValue() {
        return (Boolean) this.objectValue.get();
    }
}

package javafxtest;

import java.sql.SQLException;
import javafx.application.Application;
import static javafx.application.Application.launch;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;
import javafx.scene.control.cell.PropertyValueFactory;
import javafx.scene.layout.FlowPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class TableViewDemo extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage myStage) {
        // Set up the stage
        myStage.setTitle("Demonstrate TableView");
        FlowPane rootNode = new FlowPane(10, 10);
        rootNode.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        Scene myScene = new Scene(rootNode, 600, 450);
        myStage.setScene(myScene);

        //Set up some test data - 4 rows of 4 columns
        ObservableList<Field[]> dataModel = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
        ObservableList<Field[]> dataModel2 = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
        Field[] fields1;
        Field[] fields2;
        Field[] fields3;
        Field[] fields4;
        try {
            fields1 = new Field[4];
            fields1[0] = new Field("R1C1");
            fields1[1] = new Field(25);
            fields1[2] = new Field(100.00);
            fields1[3] = new Field(true);

            fields2 = new Field[4];
            fields2[0] = new Field("R2C1");
            fields2[1] = new Field(30);
            fields2[2] = new Field(150.00);
            fields2[3] = new Field(false);

            fields3 = new Field[4];
            fields3[0] = new Field("R3C1");
            fields3[1] = new Field(397);
            fields3[2] = new Field(1005.99);
            fields3[3] = new Field(true);

            fields4 = new Field[4];
            fields4[0] = new Field("R4C1");
            fields4[1] = new Field(1085);
            fields4[2] = new Field(1.00);
            fields4[3] = new Field(false);

            //Add the data to the dataModel
            dataModel.addAll(fields1, fields2, fields3, fields4);

            //Set up the columns ===== This is where the likely problem is, or at least part of the problem ====
            TableColumn<Field[], String> colString = new TableColumn<>("String");
            colString.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("stringValue"));
            colString.setPrefWidth(150);

            TableColumn<Field[], Integer> colInt = new TableColumn<>("int");
            colInt.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("intValue"));
            colInt.setPrefWidth(100);

            TableColumn<Field[], Double> colDouble = new TableColumn<>("double");
            colDouble.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("doubleValue"));
            colDouble.setPrefWidth(100);

            TableColumn<Field[], Boolean> colBoolean = new TableColumn<>("boolean");
            colBoolean.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("booleanValue"));
            colBoolean.setPrefWidth(75);

            //Set up the TableView - it takes an Array of Field objects. Add the data and columns to it
            TableView<Field[]> tableView = new TableView<Field[]>();
            tableView.setItems(dataModel);
            tableView.getColumns().addAll(colString, colInt, colDouble, colBoolean);

            //Print out the datamodel
            dataModel2 = tableView.getItems();
            for (int i = 0; i < dataModel2.size(); i++) {
                Field[] fields = new Field[4];
                fields = dataModel2.get(i);
                for (int j = 0; j < fields.length; j++) {
                    Field field = fields[j];
                    switch (j) {
                        case 0: //Column is a String data type
                            System.out.println(field.getStringValue());
                            break;
                        case 1:  //Column is a int data type
                            System.out.println(field.getIntValue());
                            break;
                        case 2:  //Column is a double data type
                            System.out.println(field.getDoubleValue());
                            break;
                        case 3:  //Column is a boolean data type
                            System.out.println(field.getBooleanValue());
                            break;
                        default:
                            break;
                    }
                }
            }

            // Set the tableView size
            tableView.setPrefWidth(500);
            tableView.setPrefHeight(300);

            rootNode.getChildren().add(tableView);
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            System.out.println(e.getLocalizedMessage());
        }
        myStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

This is what I currently use to populate a cell with a String value:

```
    final int x = i;
    tableColumn<Field[], String> columnString = (TableColumn<Field[], String>) this.columnModel.get(i);
    columnString.setCellValueFactory((TableColumn.CellDataFeatures<Field[], String> fieldArray) -> {
        Field arrayField = fieldArray.getValue()[x];
        return new ReadOnlyObjectWrapper(arrayField.getStringValue());
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

This simply isn't the way `PropertyValueFactory` works. From the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/javafx/scene/control/cell/PropertyValueFactory.html):

> An example of how to use this class is:
>
> ```
> TableColumn<Person,String> firstNameCol = new TableColumn<Person,String>("First Name");
> firstNameCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Person,String>("firstName"));
> ```
>
> In this example, `Person` is the class type of the `TableView` items list. The class `Person` must be declared public. `PropertyValueFactory` uses the constructor argument, `"firstName"`, to assume that `Person` has a public method `firstNameProperty` with no formal parameters and a return type of `ObservableValue<String>`.
>
> If such a method exists, then it is invoked, and additionally assumed to return an instance of `Property<String>`. The return value is used to populate the `TableCell`. In addition, the `TableView` adds an observer to the return value, such that any changes fired will be observed by the `TableView`, resulting in the cell immediately updating.
>
> If no such method exists, then `PropertyValueFactory` assumes that `Person` has a public method `getFirstName` or `isFirstName` with no formal parameters and a return type of `String`. If such a method exists, then it is invoked, and its return value is wrapped in a `ReadOnlyObjectWrapper` and returned to the `TableCell`.

So, basically, the `PropertyValueFactory` retrieves the object representing the row, and uses reflection to look for a method `xxxProperty()`, where `xxx` is the property name assigned to the `PropertyValueFactory`. If no such method exists, then as a fall-back it looks for a method `getXxx()` instead, and wraps the result, if it exists, in a `ReadOnlyObjectWrapper`.

In your case, the value representing the row is a `Field[]`, i.e. the object is an *array* of `Field`s. An array does not have a `stringValueProperty()` or `getStringValue()` method (etc), so this fails. (The individual elements of the array have those methods, of course, but the `PropertyValueFactory` isn't going to look at the array elements, it's just going to look at the value for the row, i.e. the array itself.)

It's hard to know how to "solve" this problem, as there's no really obvious reason you'd want to approach things this way anyway. You could, of course, just do

```
colString.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> 
    new SimpleStringProperty(cellData.getValue()[0].getStringValue()));
```

etc., but at that point it's not clear why you wouldn't just define a class with four regular fields - or even just use an `Object[]` and get rid of your `Field` class - anyway.

Comment: Thanks James, I suspected that there may be a fundamental problem. I have amended my question to show what I currently use to populate the cell.

Comment: The problem that I have is that I have a Swing application that I developed a few years ago that I am trying to port to JavaFX. The model is very generic in nature and has served my purpose very well, but I am now coming across the downside to the generic-ness. If the only way to make a table editable is to use properties I think I will have to forgo the benefits of editable tables, because I complete rewrite at this stage is a non-starter. Is there a way to make a table editable without properties, even if it is not as simple as with properties?

Comment: @StuartM Why not just make a `TableView<List<ObjectProperty<Object>>>`, or something similar? The cell value factory for column `i` would just be `cellData -> cellData.getValue().get(i)`. Presumably somewhere at runtime you know the actual type for each column, so you set the converter for a `TextFieldTableCell` according to that type. Again, it's not really clear what you're trying to do with the code you posted.